# find all objects present in a tree structure under a particular object

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

I have an Agent table. Each agent has 2 juniors who are infact agents themselves. Similarly each junior agent has two junior agents and so on. How can I find total no of juniors of a particular agent.

I mean total no of agents includes junior agents and their junior agents and so on.

**Agent table**

```
class CreateAgents < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.2]
  def change
    create_table :agents do |t|
      t.string :name, index: true

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

**Junior table**

```
class CreateJuniors < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.2]
  def change
    create_table :juniors do |t|
      t.references :junior, index: true
      t.references :agent, foreign_key: true

      t.timestamps
    end
    add_foreign_key :juniors, :agents, column: :junior_id
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you need to find the number of nodes in a Binary Tree.
You can do it like this:

```
def get_number_of_juniors(agent)
  if agent.nil?
    return 0
  end
  count = 0
  if agent.juniors.present?
    agent.juniors.each do |junior|
      count += get_number_of_juniors(junior)
    end
  end
  return count+1
end
```